# "ERROR: TF401444: Please sign-in at least once..." in AzureCLI@2 task

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, pull-request, azure-cli

I am using below YAML pipeline to create a PR via Azure CLI script:-

```yaml
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        # Set organization, project, and repository details
        $organization="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg"
        $project="MyProject"
        $repository="MyRepo"
        $targetBranch = "refs/heads/dev"
        $sourceBranch = "refs/heads/feature/myfeature"

        # Set the pull request title and description
        $prTitle="Automated Pull Request"
        $prDescription="Auto-generated pull request for changes."

        # Create a pull request using az repos pr create
        az repos pr create --organization $organization --project $project --repository $repository --source-branch $sourceBranch --target-branch $targetBranch --title "$prTitle" --description "$prDescription"
```

**I am receiving the error below:-**

```
# ["ERROR: TF401444: Please sign-in at least once..." in AzureCLI@2 task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663812/error-tf401444-please-sign-in-at-least-once-in-azurecli2-task)
```

Expecting to not need to explicitly log in when the service connection is specified in the **`azureSubscription`** property on the task. I have verified the service connection exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think your sign-in issue would be solved by simply adding the following to your `AzureCLI@2` task:

*Using Personal Access Token (PAT)*

```
env:
 AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT) # <-- This is your pipeline variable containing your PAT
```

*Example full code*

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT)
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      scriptType: ps
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        # Set organization, project, and repository details
        $organization="https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg"
        $project="MyProject"
        $repository="MyRepo"
        $targetBranch = "refs/heads/dev"
        $sourceBranch = "refs/heads/feature/myfeature"

        # Set the pull request title and description
        $prTitle="Automated Pull Request"
        $prDescription="Auto-generated pull request for changes."

        # Create a pull request using az repos pr create
        az repos pr create --organization $organization --project $project --repository $repository --source-branch $sourceBranch --target-branch $targetBranch --title "$prTitle" --description "$prDescription"
```

If not mistaken, once added like this in your `AzureCLI@2` it should default to using this environment variable for the authentication, and you should not have to sign-in using such as `az devops login` command.

**Update:**
I verified the above suggestion actually works, as long as you populate the `env` as suggested in the `AzureCLI@2` task, you should not need the `az devops login` command.

Ensure the PAT has at least these permissions for your scenario:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Interactive login will not work in **Azure CLI task** of DevOps pipeline.***

You need to make use of PAT token with **`az devops login`** to create PR in the Azure Repository:-

**My Azure DevOps yaml pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  organization: https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738
  project: AzureDevops
  repository: streamlitapp
  targetBranch: main
  sourceBranch: myfeature
  prTitle: Automated Pull Request
  prDescription: Auto-generated pull request for changes
  AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: xep3dv726tvoxilxxxxxxx3h4yjnpb6vnyhbjq

steps:
 - task: AzureCLI@2
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxxxx)'
     scriptType: 'bash'
     scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
     inlineScript: |
       # Set Azure DevOps organization URL
             #export AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT=xxxxxtbjz6wyryhl3h4yjnpb6vnyhbjq
       
             # Azure CLI commands to interact with Azure DevOps
             echo $(AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT) | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738
               az repos pr create --org $(organization) --project $(project) --repository $(repository) --source-branch $(sourceBranch) --target-branch $(targetBranch) --title "$(prTitle)" --description "$prDescription"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) predefined variable if you dont want to generate a PAT (and have to renew/manage it...):

```yaml
- script: |
    az pipelines build list
    az repos pr list
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'Show build list and PRs'
```

As mentioned in the provided link:

> You can configure the default scope for `System.AccessToken` using [build job authorization scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops#job-authorization-scope).